# JPA AttributeConverter not able to convert field when having @JsonProperty annotation

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jackson, lombok

JPA AttributeConverter not able to convert field when having `@JsonProperty` annotation. When the `dbAddress` json string is getting converted to `Address` entity, we are getting value for `street` field in Address class but not getting `postalAddress` field in response but we are getting the value of `zipCode` as null.

I need postalAddress in response. Please help!

The sample classes are as follows:

```
@Converter
public class AddressConverter implements 
  AttributeConverter<Address, String> {

  @Override
  public Address convertToEntityAttribute(String dbAddress) {

    ObjectMapper obj = new ObjectMapper();

    Address addr = obj.readValue(dbAddress, Address.class);

    return addr;

}
```

Also, dbAddress is having the follows:

```
{"zipCode" : "12345", "street" : "104 Downtown"}
```

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor 
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "Address")
public class Address {

@JsonProperty("postalAddress")
private String zipCode;

private String street;

}
```

I am getting response like this - `{"zipCode" : null, "street" : "104 Downtown"}` but expecting like this `{"postalAddress" : "12345", "street" : "104 Downtown"}`.
I have tried by myself and also checked in google but didn't get any desirable solution.